# How to get building elevation and levels

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-gis, google-elevation-api

Is there any API or DataSet available to know the Building elevation and levels based on lat and long.
I need data for North America(USA)

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask will be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Aside this comment, if you add the needed region of your data that would be very helpful

Comment: I need Data for USA. I am okay with Opensource or Paid Data.